# DonutProgressBar value is fluctuating when I set progress value for second time

Tags: java, android

i have created a donutprogressBar and i am setting the progressbar value and its working fine for the first time but when i set the value for second time than the progressbar gets fluctuating between the first value and the second value , i want the progressbar to be set conatsntant to the second value

```
here is my code :

 strMalePercentage = jsonObject.getJSONObject("male").getString("percentage_manglik_present");
                        txtPercentage.setText("Manglik Male"+strMalePercentage);
                        Progress(strMalePercentage);

public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.btn_ManglikMatchMale){
            linearMale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearFemale.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgMatchGender.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_male1);
            txtPercentage.setText("Manglik Male");
            Progress(strMalePercentage);
            btnMale.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textPrimary));
            btnMale.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sky_blue));
            btnFemale.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_pink));
            btnFemale.setTextColor(R.color.textPrimary);
            btnMale.setTextColor(R.color.gray_light);
        }else
        { linearMale.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearFemale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            imgMatchGender.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_female1);
            txtPercentage.setText("Manglik Female ");
            Progress(strFemalePercentage);
            btnFemale.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textPrimary));
            btnFemale.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_pink));
            btnMale.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sky_blue));
            btnMale.setTextColor(R.color.textPrimary);
            btnFemale.setTextColor(R.color.gray_light);

        }

    }


public void Progress(final String Percentage){
        Timer timer;


        donutProgress = (DonutProgress) findViewById(R.id.donut_progress_male);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        double d =  Double.parseDouble(Percentage);
                        int i = (int) d;
                        donutProgress.setProgress(0);
                        donutProgress.setProgress(i);


                    }
                });
            }
        },1000,100);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you might not have stopped the timer after the first run so it keeps resetting

Comment: @iestync how to stop the timer ?

Comment: if you keep a reference of the timer outside the Progress method then you can just call `timer.cancel();` before starting the schedule again

Comment: @iestync can you tell me where i write this code timer.cancel(); ant which line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, so the timer reference is outside and you can cancel it if already running

```
private Timer timer;

public void progress(final String Percentage){

    donutProgress = (DonutProgress) findViewById(R.id.donut_progress_male);

    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
    } else {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    double d =  Double.parseDouble(Percentage);
                    int i = (int) d;
                    donutProgress.setProgress(0);
                    donutProgress.setProgress(i);


                }
            });
        }
    },1000,100);
}
```